# Amazon EC2, still cant ping or "http" it

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ping

I am new at Amazon Cloud technologies. I ve set up an Amazon Linux instance created my keys and assigned elastic IP. Also, I opened all TCP, UDP, ICMP ports(ok, it's very dangerous, but I am using it for test purposes). I ve also installed Apache server and enabled it. But still cant ping or access my instance via IP. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Please see a screenshot of the security groups settings. All ports are open...
Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s49x7.png) out

Comment: try add a 80 port in security group.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what you can and can't do and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I can make ssh connections, and of course to use the admin interface of aws console. But neither can ping my instance nor "http" to the apache server I just installed. Check my edits please...

Answer (score 2):

Use the key (the .pem file) to connect to the instance.  You can get the address from looking at the instance in the EC2 console... it's at the bottom when you select one.

just do

```
$ ssh -i [keyfile.pem] ec2-user@[address from the console]
```

that will get you in.  Also, you can try telnet to make sure it is listening

```
$ telnet [address from the console] 22
```

That will connect to the SSH port over telnet which will let you know if it's up.  You won't be able to log in this way however.

EDIT = sorry, I didn't catch the part about apache for some reason.

check iptables

```
$ iptables -L
```

Add a rule for port 80 if you need

```
$ iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: He installed apapche, so he logged in so he has port 22 up.

Comment: Yeap, I already can make ssh connections.

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  2 things then. 1) check the Security Group.  2) check iptables.

Comment: Thank you...as you can see from my edits(screenshot), all ports are open. I added this rule on IP Tables and I executed iptables -L after that. Still cant connect to port 80

Comment: is apache running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to EC2 console and in the security tab configure the firewall to open ports, ICMP (ping) and UDP if needed. This is stateless firewall on incoming packets only. By default it allows only SSH (tcp/22).

Comment: Hello Andrew, Please check my edits